# Adding Java builder to .project file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, builder

I need to add a Java builder to mt .project file in Eclipse. However, there is no such file in my project folder. I don't know where this file is, maybe you can help me out?

Comment: Check your eclipse workspace folder you will be able to see .project file there

Comment: You might want to clarify why you think you want to add a builder by editing the .project file. There's more to converting a project to a Java project than adding a builder, if that's what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, the .project file is kept in the root directory of your project, which is in your workspace. It's easy to see if you do a directory listing in your underlying filesystem. If you want to find out where your workspace is, find it by looking at the project in the Package Explorer. right-click > Properties > Resource > Location.

It might be better to use Eclipse itself to add a builder to your project, for example, using the Package Explorer - project right-click > Properties > Builders feature.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the project into a faceted project. This generally happens when you import a project from git and the project is not a java project.

Steps:

1. Right Click -> Properties -> Project Facets
2. Click on convert project into a faceted project
3. Select the builder as java builder.

Answer (score 0):

Ankit's instructions work for me.

The Menu name has changed from 'Project Facets' to 'Project Natures' and you now click 'Add' ->  'Java builder'. There are various warning about using this so called advanced operation that you need to acknowledge.

Once you have done the above, you will probably need to change the settings in Java Build Path so the 'src' path and libraries are set correctly.